# Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, web-applications

I am writing a Web Application in ASP.NET using C#. Whenever I run it, I get three types of Runtime Javascript Errors.

My Problem is that even though I am running a new Web Application with out any modification, then I also get the same errors.

**These are the errors:**

1. Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
   at 
   `document.addEventListener("mousemove", updateLastMouseMoveCoordinates, false);`
2. Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected
   at `divSurveyInit();`
3. Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method
   at 
   `document.addEventListener("mousemove", updateLastMouseMoveCoordinates, false);`

Comment: Errors 1 and 3 are identical. Copy/paste error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For IE versions < 9 you have to use the [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to add event listeners.

Answer (score 1):

You can use attachEvent or addEventListener in an `if...else` for different versions of IE and/or cross browsers like this or similar:

```
if (document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', changeState, true);
        document.addEventListener('mouseout', stopScrollingIfOutsideWindow, true);
        document.addEventListener('mousedown', markMouseDown, true);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', unmarkMouseDown, true);
} else if (document.attachEvent){
        document.attachEvent('onmousemove', changeState);
        document.attachEvent('onmouseout', stopScrollingIfOutsideWindow);
        document.attachEvent('onmousedown', markMouseDown);
        document.attachEvent('onmouseup', unmarkMouseDown);
}
```